# Why do the symmetries of a tetrahedron contain no odd permutations?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, polyhedra

[This video "Symmetries of a Tetrahedron"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2g7gYebaIBs) shows that the rotational group of a tetrahedron is isomorphic to the alternating group $A_4$.

At time 0:42, it shows that it is geometrically impossible to obtain an odd permutation like $(1 \; 2)$ by rotations. However, how to formally prove it? My main concern here is that how to argue that the symmetries of a tetrahedron do not contain $(1 \; 2)$ does *not* because we may miss some rotations.

Then, at time 0:48, it shows how to obtain odd permutations by turning the tetrahedron inside out. I don't understand *how* the tetrahedron is turned inside out. Could you please explain it?

Comment: Do you know what the alternating group is?  Do you know that the alternating group contains only even permutations?  Do you know that however you combine even permutations that the result will again be an even permutation?  Do you understand then that by contraposition, if you have an odd permutation that it could not have been formed using only even permutations and thus could not be achieved solely by using the elements in the alternating group?

Comment: As for the turning the tetrahedron inside out bit, what don't you understand about it?  How to visualize the new type of symmetry?  Why this new type of symmetry isn't ordinarily used?  To visualize it, take a tetrahedron where the base is immobile but the top can be moved and push the top straight down, through the base to the other side.  As for why this symmetry isn't normally used... because no rigid physical tetrahedron can be manipulated in such a fashion using rotations alone in our physical universe.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks. I don't understand *how* the tetrahedron is turned inside out. Now, I understand it according to the detailed description you give.

Comment: @JMoravitz As for the odd/even issue, my concern is that how to argue that the symmetries of a tetrahedron do not contain $(1 \; 2)$ does *not* because we may miss some rotations.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ABCD$ be the tetrahedron and consider

$$K=\det\pmatrix{A-B\\A-C\\A-D}$$

Swapping two vertices from among $B,C$ and $D$ amounts to swapping two rows in the determinant, so it changes the sign of $K$.
Swapping $A$ with another vertex $X$ amounts to subtracting the row $A-X$ from the other two rows and multiplying the row $A-X$ by $-1$. The end result is once again the sign of $K$ changes.

It follows that an odd permutation -- as a composition of an odd number of swaps -- must change the sign of $K$.

Now, we need only show that a rotation leaves the sign of $K$ unchanged. Do you think you can take it from here?